# Qtcreator with C++11 thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, qt-creator

I wrote hello world programme for C++11 thread. I am using qtcreator ide with gcc 4.9.1 but i am not able to run the programme. It compiles properly. But when i run, it gives the following warning

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Enable multithreading to use std::thread: Operation not permitted
```

My project.pro file is

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
LIBS += -pthread
```

and main.cpp is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
void hello()
{
    std::cout<<"Hello Concurrent World\n";
}
int  main()
{
    std::thread t(hello);
    t.join();
}
```

On thing i observed is that it use

```
g++ -c -pipe -std=c++11 -g -Wall -W -fPIE  -I/usr/lib/qt/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -o main.o main.cpp
```

to create main.o object file and

```
g++ -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro -o project main.o   -pthread
```

to create executable. It i remove --as-needed from the command used to create the executable. It works fine.Please let me know the proper solution so that i can use qtcreator for C++11 threads.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug in libstdc++. As a workaround, do not use `--as-needed` if C++ threads are used.

[See here](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2013-09/msg00163.html).